# Position view bottom without using a spacer

Tags: position, swiftui

How can I position a View at the bottom without using a spacer. I know I can achieve it placing a spacer and my view in inside a VStack but I don't want to use a spacer because I don't want my view to take up all the vertical space. With UIKit I would position it at safe area bottom guide.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is to add a frame for the `container` view.

```
Group{ // container View
    Text("iner label")
}.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
```

If you don't add frame, the default frame will wrap the inner view and has the same size as the inner View. If you add a frame, it will create a space belonging to the outer view, in the UIView concept, it's a superView. Then you will see what you will need to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Experimenting with different approaches I finally end up with creating own custom container, which, having some known limitation, fulfils my needs completely. Hope it would be helpful for someone else.

Demo:

[image: PinnedView Demo1]

Pros: ContentView & PinnedView are absolutely independent in layout on each other, automatically handle device orientation, and actually limitless in internal content

Cons: Due to used `GeometryReader` using `.infinity` at top-level content or pinned view result in crash due to "chicken-egg" problem.

Container code:

```
struct ContainerWithPinnedBottomView<Content, Pinned>: View 
                                     where Content: View, Pinned: View {

    private var content: () -> Content
    private var bottomView: () -> Pinned

    @inlinable public init(@ViewBuilder pinnedView: @escaping () -> Pinned,
                            @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.bottomView = pinnedView
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.clear) // !! Extends ZStack to full screen
            GeometryReader { _ in
                ZStack {
                    self.content()
                }
            }
            self.bottomView()
                .alignmentGuide(.bottom) { $0[.bottom] }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Usage example (of demo screenshot)

```
struct TestBottomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ContainerWithPinnedBottomView(pinnedView: {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Always Pinned to Bottom")
                    .padding()
    //                .frame(width: .infinity) // !! LIMITATION - don't use, cycling crash
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color.blue)
        }) {
            NavigationView {
                List (0 ..< 100, id: \.self) { i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Other")) {
                        Text("Row \(i)")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("TitleBar")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position property will help you try this way

```
Group{ // container View
     Text("iner label")
}.position(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without geometry reader you can use overlay modifier.

Credit goes to @Asperi's answer

```
struct ContainerWithPinnedBottomView<Content: View, Pinned: View>: View {
    private var content: () -> Content
    private var bottomView: () -> Pinned

    init(
        @ViewBuilder pinnedView: @escaping () -> Pinned,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self.content = content
        self.bottomView = pinnedView
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.clear // !! Extends ZStack to full screen
            self.content()
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, content: bottomView)
        // .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: bottomView)
    }
}
```