# How to put a control in particular position in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Set label to specific X, Y Position in View. Don’t want to use Vstack or HStack.

Comment: Your description is not proper that is why down vote. Check, this may be useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59169778/7368016

Answer (score 0):

you can use position:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
        .position(x: 100, y: 100)
    }
}
```