# Alignment changes after adding a GeometryReader

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I had a layout that essentially looked like this:

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            Text("Centered")
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
    Group {
        GeometryReader { geometry in // This GeometryReader is causing issues.
            VStack {
                Text("I want this at the bottom")
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: nil, alignment: .topLeading)
        }
    }
}
```

When this is rendered, both Text elements are rendered in the center of the screen. The second text element's container takes up the entire width of the screen, which is intended. If I remove the problematic GeometryReader, then the text is properly rendered at the bottom of the screen, but obviously the frame is not set to the entire width of the screen. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default SwiftUI containers tight to content, but `GeometryReader` consumes maximum of available space. So if to remove second `GeometryReader` the `VStack` just wraps internal `Text`.

If it is still needed to keep second `GeometryReader` (to read `width`) and put text to the bottom, the simplest approach would be to add `Spacer` as below

[image]

```
Group {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("I want this at the bottom")
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: nil, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

Alternate approach of how to stick view at bottom you can find in my answer in this post [Position view bottom without using a spacer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328375/12299030)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            GeometryReader {geometry in
                Text("Centered")
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                    .background(Color.red)
            }
            WidthReader {w in
                Text("I want this at the bottom").frame(width: w)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct WidthReader<Content: View>: View {
    let widthContent: (CGFloat) -> Content
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var height: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {g in
            widthContent(width).background(
                GeometryReader {g1 in
                    Spacer().onAppear {height = g1.size.height}.onChange(of: g1.size.height, perform: {height = $0})
                }
            ).onAppear {width = g.size.width}.onChange(of: g.size.width, perform: {width = $0})
        }.frame(height: height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add the `.fixedSize()` modifier to your `Stack`.