# Align rectangle to be within certain distance of safe area bottom edge SWIFTUI

Tags: swift, user-interface, layout, constraints, swiftui

I am used to Interface Builder and layout constraints but now I want to convert my app to Swift UI. What I am trying to do right now is align the top edge of the view marked with a 1 to be within a certain distance of the safe area bottom edge (marked with a 2) so that the top edge that is now at 1 will then be at position 3. I tried using spacers but then it will look different on smaller devices such as an iPhone 8. In IB I could have used a simple layout constraint. How does this work in Swift UI? I have attached the relevant code and an image. Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .orange
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack{
                Spacer()

                ZStack{
                    Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, opacity: 0.1))

                    Image("")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                    .shadow(radius: 10)

                }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .center)

                Spacer(minLength: 100)

                ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
                    ExtractedView()
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                }

            }

            .navigationBarTitle(Text("You See"))
            .navigationBarHidden(false)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewDevice("iPhone")
    }
}

struct ExtractedView: View {
    @State private var name: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: .top){
                VStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 7)
                        .padding(.top)

                    Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                        Text("Start advertising")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    }.padding(.top)

                    TextField("Test", text: $name)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(20))
                        .padding()

                }


                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .fill(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, opacity: 0.1))
                    .zIndex(-5)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The approach provided in post [Position view bottom without using a spacer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328375/12299030) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to solve my problem. The trick is to create two VStacks with different frame alignments. The outer VStack has top alignment so that the Discover view can be at the top. The inner VStack has a bottom alignment so that the sheet can be pulled up from the bottom. Space will be filled from the bottom up in this case.

```
VStack{
        Discover()
            .padding(.top, 60.0)
        VStack{
            Text("Recent Messages:")
                .font(.headline)

            DetailSheet()
                .offset(x: 0, y: 0)
        }.frame(width: g.size.width, height: (g.size.height - g.size.width - 80 + 200), alignment: .bottom)

    }
    .frame(width: g.size.width, height: g.size.height, alignment: .top)
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]you can try this:

offset -10 is just your offset you want to have....

i hope i understood you right, i am not so sure...

```
var body: some View {
        VStack{
      //      ZStack(alignment: .top){
                VStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 7)
                        .padding(.top)

                    Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                        Text("Start advertising")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    }.padding(.top)

                    TextField("Test", text: $name)
                        .padding(.all)
                        .background(Color.white.cornerRadius(20))
                        .padding()

                }.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                .fill(Color(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, opacity: 0.1))
                ).offset(y:-10)



            }
    //    }
```