# In SwiftUI, how do I draw a view above a bottom toolbar?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view with a bottom toolbar. When some user action is performed, I would like to display a drawer coming from the bottom that will cover this toolbar. I wasn't able to find a way to do this - the toolbar always remains on top. Here's an example of something I've tried:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Bottom Text")
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .bottom)
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                            Text("Bottom Bar")
                        }
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The "Bottom Text" label gets hidden behind the bottom toolbar.

The one thing I've tried so far is to remove the .toolbar modifier when the drawer is shown (by creating a custom view modifier that returns the .toolbar modifier conditionally). This works but seems like a hack, and also has some UI artifacts as the removal of the toolbar can shift some of the other view.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding condition to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59328375/12299030 (for `self.bottomView`) you can achieve your goal.

Answer (score 4):

To show content *on top* of the bottom toolbar, add your views as an overlay on the NavigationView itself:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                    Button("Bottom Bar", action: {})
                }
            }
    }
    .overlay(
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Bottom Text")
        }
    )
}
```

**Original answer:**
Remove the `ignoresSafeArea`. The bottom safe area includes the toolbar, so by ignoring it you’re telling Swiftui to put the content behind the toolbar.

Comment: In that case the content is put ABOVE the toolbar (not OVER it, like I need it). I need a drawer that comes up from the very bottom of the screen, over the toolbar.

Comment: @YarivAdam Ah, well you did ask how to put the content “above” it! Anyway, I have edited my answer to show how to put the content *over / on top of* the toolbar.